# Convert data type for a list of variables in R

Tags: r

I wanted to convert a list of character variables in a data frame to numeric format. I used TRANSFORM and LAPPLY functions.

Method 1

```
var <- c('year', 'age', 'days', 'visits')
df <- lapply(var, function(x) {transform(df, x = as.numeric(x))}
```

Method 2

```
var <- c('year', 'age', 'days', 'visits')
for (i in 1:length(var)) {
    transform(df, df$var[i] = as.numeric(var[i])
}
```

But none of them worked.

Could someone tell where the problem is? What is the correct ways to achieve this goal? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, we can subset the dataset with the columns, loop over the subset of data with `lapply` and apply `as.numeric`

```
df[var] <- lapply(df[var], as.numeric)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(var), as.numeric)
```